# Too much recursion on ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax

Here is the code of my register.js page:

```
$(document).on('pagecreate', '#register', function() {
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        $('.frmFields').removeClass('error');
        var errors = 0;

        var fields = {
            username: $('#username'),
            name: $('#name'),
            email: $('#email'),
            password: $('#password'),
            vPassword: $('#password_verify'),
            dob: $('#dob')
        };

        $.each(fields, function(key, value) {
            if (value.val() == '') {
                value.addClass('error');
                errors++;

                alert('שדה ' + key + ' הינו שדה חובה');
            }

            if (key == 'name') {
                if (!isText(value.val())) {
                    value.addClass('error');
                    errors++;

                    alert('שדה שם חייב להכיל טקסט בלבד');
                }
            }

            if (key == 'email') {
                if (!isEmailAddress(value.val())) {
                    value.addClass('error');
                    errors++;

                    alert('שדה דואר אלקטרוני חייב להכיל כתובת תקנית');
                }
            }
        });

        if (fields.password.val() != fields.vPassword.val()) {
            vPassword.addClass('error');
            errors++;

            alert('הסיסמאות שהקלדת אינן זהות');
        }

        function checkUsername(uname) {
            var valid = false;

            $.ajax({
                url: './actions/checkUsername.php',
                type: 'GET',
                async: false,
                data: {
                    username: fields.username.val()
                },
                success: function(resp) {
                    if (resp == "success")
                        $('#valid').val('true');
                    else
                        $('#valid').val('false');
                }
            });
        }

        checkUsername(fields.username.val());

        if ($('#valid').val() == 'true') {
            $.ajax({
                url: './actions/register.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: fields,
                success: function(resp) {
                    if (resp == "success") {
                        alert('yay!');
                    } else
                        alert(resp);
                }
            });
        } else
            alert('שם המשתמש שבחרת תפוס');
    });
});
```

Everything is working fine, the data is being sent correctly, only that I get an error:

> too much reccursion

It happens because of the last $.ajax call. I tried it with $.post and it does the same.

How can I do this correctly so I won't get this error?

Comment: ~~deleted (never mind)~~

Comment: @StephenThomas `async` is set to false.

Comment: It actually does have a value... with alerts it works well but when I call the ajax request it gives me that error...

Comment: Unrelated, but since you have an object of the fields, why not just make it an object of field values and associated the validation function as well and eliminate the nested `if`s as you iterate the values?

Comment: Also unrelated, but you probably want to prevent the default action.

Comment: Can't see any recursion happening in your code; it maybe is related with other event handlers triggering. I would suggest to `return false` at the end of the submit handler to cancel the default action (this is what Dave is suggesting, in case it was not clear). But I also wonder why you don't do the register Ajax immediately, and let the server do the name check as a part of it. The response could then give the information on which part failed, if any.

Comment: Why define `checkUsername` function within `click` event?

Comment: It's the other way around - You should encapsulate the register ajax logic inside a function, then extract the content of `checkUsername` out of the function and in the `success` callback you should call the new **register** function

Comment: Also - Maybe change `$(document).on('pagecreate', '#register', function() {` to `$(document).one('pagecreate', '#register', function() {` - To prevent multiple bindings of the `click` event on the `#submit` button

Comment: Is `'pagecreate'` event called more than once?

Comment: This is because of event bubbling. Your .Click methods are getting called again and again.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you are passing jQuery objects in the data part of your ajax call. Instead have the values.

```
    var data = {
        username: $('#username').val(),
        name: $('#name').val(),
        email: $('#email').val(),
        password: $('#password').val(),
        vPassword: $('#password_verify').val(),
        dob: $('#dob').val()
    };
```

```
        $.ajax({
            url: './actions/register.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            success: function(resp) {
                if (resp == "success") {
                    alert('yay!');
                } else
                    alert(resp);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:

```
$(document).one('pagecreate', '#register', function() {
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        $('.frmFields').removeClass('error');
        var errors = 0;

        // BUG HERE - Take a look at @Musa's answer
        var fields = {
            username: $('#username'),
            name: $('#name'),
            email: $('#email'),
            password: $('#password'),
            vPassword: $('#password_verify'),
            dob: $('#dob')
        };

        $.each(fields, function(key, value) {
            if (value.val() == '') {
                value.addClass('error');
                errors++;

                alert('שדה ' + key + ' הינו שדה חובה');
            }

            if (key == 'name') {
                if (!isText(value.val())) {
                    value.addClass('error');
                    errors++;

                    alert('שדה שם חייב להכיל טקסט בלבד');
                }
            }

            if (key == 'email') {
                if (!isEmailAddress(value.val())) {
                    value.addClass('error');
                    errors++;

                    alert('שדה דואר אלקטרוני חייב להכיל כתובת תקנית');
                }
            }
        });

        if (fields.password.val() != fields.vPassword.val()) {
            vPassword.addClass('error');
            errors++;

            alert('הסיסמאות שהקלדת אינן זהות');
        }

        function registerUsername() {
            if ($('#valid').val() == 'true') {
                $.ajax({
                    url: './actions/register.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: fields,
                    success: function(resp) {
                        if (resp == "success") {
                            alert('yay!');
                        } else
                            alert(resp);
                    }
                });
            } else
                alert('שם המשתמש שבחרת תפוס');
            }
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: './actions/checkUsername.php',
            type: 'GET',
            async: false,
            data: {
                username: fields.username.val()
            },
            success: function(resp) {
                if (resp == "success")
                    $('#valid').val('true');
                else
                    $('#valid').val('false');
                registerUsername();
            }
        });       
    });
});
```

- I have changed `$(document).on('pagecreate', '#register', function() {` **TO** `$(document).one('pagecreate', '#register', function() {` in order to prevent multiple `click` bindings on the `#submit` button
- Made the register login called **after** you check the username validity

Please note that you can put the `registerUsername` function outside the `click` event, making it available to other functions within the same scope the 'registerUsername' function is.

**EDIT:**

A different approach is to delegate the click event to the element:

```
$(document).on('click', '#register #submit', function() {
    -- PUT HERE THE SUBMIT LOGIC --
});
```

This way you don't need to use the `pagecreate` event, because you're binding the `click` event to the button, even when it still doesn't exist inside the DOM (Thanks **@charlietfl** - Now I understand what you meant in the comments below).

Please note that eventually **@Musa**'s answer is the correct one. But i'll leave my answer here too because of the event delegation suggestion and that fact that you're calling `register.php` before the `checkUsername.php` call is complete (My answer shows a possible alternative)

Comment: Or just delegate the submit listener

Comment: What is purpose of defining `registerUsername` function within `click` event?

Comment: @guest271314 - You're correct - I wrote in the question body that it's also possible to put it outside the click event (I've just wanted to keep the solution similar to the original code in the question)

Comment: @charlietfl - Do you mean `$(document).on('click', ''#submit'', function() {` ?

Comment: @charlietfl Does binding this way prevents the `click` callback function to be called multiple times If, for example, i'll run the following **5 times**: `$('#register').trigger('pagecreate');` ?

Comment: Would remove it from 'pagecreate' though and would only every get called once

Comment: @charlietfl Not sure I understand the benefits of the delegation here - I have created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e407dpLv/1/) and bound the same event 3 times using delegation, and when I click on the paragraph - The click callback  execute 3 times

Comment: But why would you bind it 3 times? If removed from `'pagecreate'` event would only get called once on page load

Comment: My guess is that the OP trigger the `pagecreate` event on the `'#register'` element multiple times (Or else - Why would they get the **too much reccursion** error) As far as I can tell, this can only happen if the `click` event was bound to the `#sumbit` a lot of times due to the `pagecreate` event. Of course - I'll delete this answer if it turn out that I was wrong

Comment: @charlietfl Only now I completely understand what you suggested. Thanks very much!

Comment: Actually pretty sure the  recursion is from `$.param` trying to handle jQuery objects instead of values as other answer shows